# ListView with Volley NetworkImageView flickering

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-volley, networkimageview

I have a pretty simple listview with a NetworkImageView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ladder_item, parent, false);
            }

            image0= (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ladder_item_layer_0_user_0_image);
            image0.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.test_random_size);
            image0.setImageUrl(obj.getImageUrl(), mLoader);

            return convertView;
        }
```

The issue is that the scroll is not as smooth as I'd like it to be, it's a bit flickering. If I comment out the "setImageUrl" line, the scroll is super smooth, so the issue is with the Volley NetworkImageView image loading. Is there anything I can do to make it less flickering?

I'm testing on a Samsung S5 mini.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have two options.

1. Change the image loader to something more performant for your particular case, like picasso or glide.
2. Resize the bitmap post loading to imageview, but i encurage the first option because volley is so last year.

Comment: Well, Volley has already few yers. What do you mean with "Resize the bitmap post loading to imageview"? Thanks

Comment: Set the size to the NetworkImageView and volley will do the resize for you.

Comment: I tried with Picasso: same result, still flickering

Comment: What is the size of your images in average?

Comment: around 1000x1000px

Comment: You really need to resize the images , please see this link to see how you can do this with picasso. https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit

Answer (score 0):

The reason for a not smooth scroll can be various. [Here](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) a really good article about the best practice you should follow for ListView.

In my case the flickering was caused by Volley image loading, the solution was to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for the image loading. Glide comes from Google folks and it's really powerful and lightweight. Now the scroll it's simply super smooth.

[Here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) a comparison between [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and Glide.